# Why does this recursive method break in IE? using JSON

Tags: javascript, json, internet-explorer, recursion

In using the following code it works in all browsers except IE where it returns an error saying that the line 'if(data[item].sub !== null)' is null or undefined. I set the sub property of the JSON object to null on purpose so that I can test for this and make sure there is a value associated with that 'sub'property. only IE breaks in all versions.

```
            createDropDownCode: function(arr){
            // loop through li's of primary menu
            that.find("li").each(function(idx){

                $(this).append( menusort(arr.menu[idx].sub) );

                $('#PrimNav div.menu').hide();

                function menusort(data){
                    if(data !== null)
                        var html = "<div class='menu'><ul>";    

                    var data_count = 0;

                    for(item in data){

                        data.length-1 == data_count ? html += "<li class='last'>" : html += "<li>";

                        if(data[item].sub !== null){
                            if(typeof(data[item].sub) === 'object'){

                                html += "<a href='" + data[item].link + "'><span>" + data[item].name + "</span></a>";

                                if($.isArray(data[item].sub)){
                                    html += menusort(data[item].sub);
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        html += "</li>"
                        data_count += 1;

                    }

                    if(data !== null)
                        html += "</ul></div>";

                    return html;
                }
```

JSON Passed to 'createDropDownCode' function....

```
var JSON = {
    menu: [
        {id: '0',sub: [
            {name: 'lorem ipsum 0-0',link: '0-0', sub: null},
            {name: 'lorem ipsum 0-1',link: '0-1', sub: null},
            {name: 'lorem ipsum 0-2',link: '0-2', sub: null}
            ]
        },
        {id: '1',sub: null},
        {id: '2',sub: [
            {name: 'lorem ipsum 2-0',link: '2-0', sub: null},
            {name: 'lorem ipsum 2-1',link: '2-1', sub: null},
            {name: 'lorem ipsum 2-2',link: '2-2', sub: [
                {name: 'lorem ipsum 2-2-0',link: '2-2-0', sub: null},
                {name: 'lorem ipsum 2-2-1',link: '2-2-1', sub: null},
                {name: 'lorem ipsum 2-2-2',link: '2-2-2', sub: [
                    {name: 'lorem ipsum 2-2-2-0',link: '2-2-2-0', sub: null},
                    {name: 'lorem ipsum 2-2-2-1',link: '2-2-2-1', sub: null},
                    {name: 'lorem ipsum 2-2-2-2',link: '2-2-2-2', sub: null},
                    {name: 'lorem ipsum 2-2-2-3',link: '2-2-2-3', sub: null}
                ]},
                {name: 'lorem ipsum 2-2-3',link: '2-2-3', sub: null},
                {name: 'lorem ipsum 2-2-4',link: '2-2-4', sub: null},
                {name: 'lorem ipsum 2-2-5',link: '2-2-5', sub: null},
                {name: 'lorem ipsum 2-2-6',link: '2-2-6', sub: null}
            ]},
            {name: 'lorem ipsum 2-3',link: '2-3', sub: [
                {name: 'lorem ipsum 2-3-0',link: '2-3-0', sub: null},
                {name: 'lorem ipsum 2-3-1',link: '2-3-1', sub: null},
                {name: 'lorem ipsum 2-3-2',link: '2-3-2', sub: [
                    {name: 'lorem ipsum 2-3-2-0',link: '2-3-2-0', sub: null},
                    {name: 'lorem ipsum 2-3-2-1',link: '2-3-2-1', sub: null},
                    {name: 'lorem ipsum 2-3-2-2',link: '2-3-2-2', sub: null},
                    {name: 'lorem ipsum 2-3-2-3',link: '2-3-2-3', sub: null}
                ]},
                {name: 'lorem ipsum 2-2-6',link: '2-3-3', sub: null}
            ]},
            {name: 'lorem ipsum 2-4',link: '2-4', sub: null},
            {name: 'lorem ipsum 2-5',link: '2-5', sub: null}
            ]
        },
        {id: '3',sub: null},
        {id: '4',sub: null},
        {id: '5',sub: null}
        ]
    }
```

Comment: Why not write `if (data === null) return "";`?

Comment: What does this line do:

data.length-1 == data_count ? html += "<li class='last'>" : html += "<li>";

?

Comment: Fabian, as I am using a for...in loop I do not have access to a variable given the current item that I am on, so a counter had to be included so that I know when I am at the end of the loop of items and add a class 'last' to that item.

Comment: @quinton I see, that's a very "hackish" way to write though. I didn't recognize it as a shortened if statement at first glance. By the way, did my answer help you? I just had another idea, could you post a working example of your code to http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: I found the answer, simple really and good that IE bugs out although not good with its response. all i needed to do was to make sure I defined the 'item' with 'var' before hand. so for(item in data) becomes for(var item in data). also I will be adding a hasOwnProperty test for good practice just inside the for loop making sure all properties belong to that object.

Comment: Ah, good find. JavaScript is a little "special" sometimes. I think it's obvious that you always expect / want a local variable in this case.

Answer (score 0):

In the JSON data, try to use `false` instead of `null`, the object type comparison is a little much in my opinion.

```
if(data[item].sub) {

    html += "<a href='" + data[item].link + "'><span>" + data[item].name + "</span></a>";

    if($.isArray(data[item].sub)) {
        html += menusort(data[item].sub);
    }
}
```

Edit: Ok, this is not the answer. As I stated in the comment above, please post a working (or not working ;)) example to http://jsfiddle.net.

Comment: thanks for the idea but changed the sub properties to be assigned null and just needed to set the item variable in the for loop to be 'for(var item in data)' missed out the 'var' keyword.